# How to suppress Indy IdHTTP error message box?

Tags: indy, http-error, idhttp, c++builder-xe7

I have an IdHTTP component and when I get a HTTP error (for example 404) Indy shows a message box. I want to handle this "silent" and prevent Indy from showing this.

I have not found any parameter to turn this off. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indy does not display message boxes.  It throws exceptions.  There are default exception handlers inside the VCL/FMX framework that will display a message box to the user if an exception is not caught in your code. So simply catch the exception in your code, eg:

```
try
{
    IdHTTP1->Get(...);
}
catch (const Exception &)
{
    // do something...
}
```

If you need finer control over the exception filtering, all Indy-specific exceptions are derived from `EIdException`, and there are many descendants (like `EIdHTTPProtocolException`), eg:

```
try
{
    IdHTTP1->Get(...);
}
catch (const EIdHTTPProtocolException &)
{
    // an HTTP error occured, do something...
    // details about the HTTP error are in the exception object
}
catch (const EIdException &)
{
    // a non-HTTP Indy error occured, do something else...
}
catch (const Exception &)
{
    // some other error occured, do something else...
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I had a try {} __finally() but it's easy to restructure. It wan't just my day today :)

Comment: @MaxKielland as a matter of writing clean code I'd suggest never doing `try...__finally`  . Instead use RAII.  FYI there's a nasty surprise waiting if you `return` within the `try` block: local objects to the function are destructed before the code in the `__finally` is executed.

Comment: Also: components may throw exceptions in response to Windows messages (not sure if TIdHTTP... does, but socket components certainly do). So you can't catch them with a `try...catch` because the exception propagates up from the main message loop, not from any of your functions. Instead you have to override the default exception handler in the global `Application` object

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Indy does not use window messages. It uses synchronous blocking socket I/O, and exceptions are raised directly by the operations being performed. [Introduction to Indy](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/IntroIndy.html)

Comment: What do you do if you don't want your UI to block while a HTTP request is in progress?

Comment: If you make the HTTP request in the main UI thread (not advisable), you can use a `TIdAntiFreeze` component to keep the message queue pumping (basically, it allows Indy components to call `Application.ProcessMessages()` periodically when they are doing things in the main UI thread).  Otherwise, move the HTTP request to its own worker thread (this is the preferred solution).